# Improve mapping effect QGIS

Tags: qgis, style, mapping

I have a set of points with latitude/longitude coordinates and some value that I want to map using QGIS software.

When I import my points and apply a graduated style I obtain the following map. On the latter all the points are visible and the overall effet is not nice from my point of vue.

Is there a way to improve that ? I'd like to have a smooth and continuous field.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change the style of your point symbol (reducing its size and setting a transparent boundary). As your point seem to be a regular grid, you could also use squares instead of circles. You can also increase the number of classes if you want a more "continuous" rendering.

EDIT : In order to change the size of your symbol when you zoom, you can set the size in "map unit" instead of "millimeter". If you set this size as the distance between two points, you will end up with a "raster like" style. Alternatively, you can convert to raster, which will be more stable if you work with different projections.

[image]

Comment: This method works but is not really optimal as the size of the squares will not adapt when I zoom or de-zoom.

Comment: If your points are on a regularly spaced grid then you might consider converting them to a raster

Comment: @ZKB: see my edit if you want to solve your zoom in and out issue.

Comment: Instead of setting the border colour to transparent, you can set the Outline style from `Solid Line` to `No Pen` with just two clicks.